# C imprimir nome com scanf

Tags: c, scanf

Eu tenho o seguinte código, o problema é que este devolve a string2 como '(null)'. Como resolvo? e porque é que isto acontece?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *string;
    char *string2;

    printf("Primeiro nome: ");
    scanf("%s", string);

    printf("Ultimo sobrenome: ");
    scanf("%s", string2);

    printf("Ola senhor %s %s. Bem-vindo.\n", string, string2);

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: `string` e `string2` são apontadores. Mas eles não apontam para lado nenhum concreto.

Comment: Mas str1 chega a imprimir

Comment: Foi azar! Se o programa tivesse estourado (ou tivesse impresso "null") não te levava a pensar que essa parte estava bem.

Comment: inputs: str1 = foo, str2 = bar... Está a imprimir "Ola senhor foo (null). Bem-vindo.". Ok então como resolvo? Não queria ter de definir um numero limitado ('char[99]')

Comment: Tentou com `gets` em vez de `scanf` e `puts` em vez de `printf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experimenta com arrays em vez de ponteiros

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[1000];  // array em vez de ponteiro
    char string2[1000]; // array em vez de ponteiro

    printf("Primeiro nome: ");
    if (scanf("%999s", string) != 1) /* erro */;

    printf("Ultimo sobrenome: ");
    if (scanf("%999s", string2) != 1) /* erro */;

    printf("Ola senhor %s %s. Bem-vindo.\n", string, string2);

    return 0;
}
```

Se queres mesmo usar ponteiros, tens que alocar espaço para as strings, e libertar esse espaço quando deixar de ser necessário:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc() and friends */

int main(void)
{
    char *string;
    char *string2;

    string = malloc(1000);            /* aloca espaco */
    if (string == NULL) /* erro */;
    string2 = malloc(1000);           /* aloca espaco */
    if (string2 == NULL) /* erro */;

    printf("Primeiro nome: ");
    if (scanf("%999s", string) != 1) /* erro */;

    printf("Ultimo sobrenome: ");
    if (scanf("%999s", string2) != 1) /* erro */;

    printf("Ola senhor %s %s. Bem-vindo.\n", string, string2);

    free(string);   /* liberta espaco */
    free(string2);  /* liberta espaco */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isto mesmo. Uma pergunta: Temos mesmo de definir um limite de bytes(chars) antecipadamente(malloc)?

Comment: O numero de bytes a alocar pde ser determinado pelo programa; não precisa ser definido pelo programador.

Answer (score -3):

Nâo é necessário usar ponteiros aqui, neste código, o uso de ponteiros só dificulta as coisas. Você pode só criar a variavel normalmente e usar o `scanf` com um `&` antes das variaveis.

O certo seria fazer o seguinte:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void limpaBuf() {
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){};
}

int main()
{
    char nome[100];
    char sobrenome[100];

    printf("Primeiro nome: ");
    scanf(" %s", &nome);

    // Limpa o buffer
    limpabuf();

    printf("Ultimo sobrenome: ");
    scanf(" %s", &sobrenome);

    printf("Ola senhor %s %s. Bem-vindo.\n", nome, sobrenome);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esse código nem funciona, tem tantos erros: 1) Na declaração de função `limpaBuf()` a variável `c` não foi declarada. 2) Na linha `scanf(" %s", &nome);` o formato `%s` significa tipo `char *` mas `&nome` é do tipo `char *[100]`. 3) Na linha `limpabuf();` a função `limpabuf();` não foi declarada. 4) Na linha `scanf(" %s", &sobrenome);` o formato `%s` significa tipo `char *` mas `&sobrenome` é do tipo `char *[100]`. 5) A função `limpaBuf()` é uma gambiarra desnecessária. Fora a qualidade das informações *"...o uso de ponteiros só dificulta as coisas..."*.